# Android SDKs don't show up

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I went through all the steps on the android dev site, installed all the SDKs, and when I start a new android project or go to android preferences the list that's supposed to show the SDKs is empty. I have the SDK location pointed to `/android-sdk-mac_x86` and it looks like every things there. Am I missing a step maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a fresh install. This should fix your problem. Sometimes eclipse will bug out and create problems.

Doing a fresh install usually solves this problem for me and people i know.

Comment: Fresh install of the SDK or of Eclipse?

Comment: Both. Basically just work through the steps on the website again. With a fresh installation of eclipse.

Comment: For some reason the sdk manager showed different things were installed depending on whether I accessed it directly or through Eclipse (via Windows > Android SDK Manager).  Deleting whatever I had downloaded in the SDK manager and then re-downloading via the one within eclipse (making sure to run eclipse as administrator), worked.

Did not need to re-install either.

Comment: Fresh intallation is very time consuming process. suggest some other idea plz.

Answer (score 1):

When you install the SDK you need to open the SDK Manager and download all the version you want to work with.. by default it doesn't include any.

Comment: @Chris: If you have already done all that, you may just need to do the installation over again. Eclipse can be kinda picky sometimes. Eclipse may have failed to do something properly. I usually try a fresh install again to ensure everything was done correctly.

Comment: @prolink007 Thanks, I'll give that a go

Comment: @Chris: if it still fails, let us know. And make sure that you are following these steps very closely http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: @Chris in your question it looks that you already installed the ADT plugin for Eclipse. Did you check for updates for the plugin?

Comment: @SERPRO Yes, I did check for the updates before I installed the SDKs the first time

Comment: @prolink007 The fresh install worked, every things showing up now

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to the fact that you didn't install the Eclipse ADT.

The SDK is one thing (and it is not linked to Eclipse), you have then to link the SDK to Eclipse.

Quite easy and very well explained here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: He already said that Eclipse ADT was installed and checked for updates. must be something else.

Answer (score -1):

it is the problem we face many time in eclipse.
to solve this problem you need to Clear your cache and reload.
just follow below given step

### open AVD manager

The clear-cache button is in Tools > Options.
and reloading is Packages > Reload in the SDK Manager.
also seled first check box in other category which force https insteam of http.
restart AVD and Eclipse