# why there is dependency among android sdks?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3, qemu, android-image

what i want to install is ARM EABI, but i have to select lots of sdks which i have installed, and it is terrible to download them all for broken network:(

i just wonder, why there is so sophisticate dependency among android sdk?

[image: dependencies among sdks]

by the way, is SDK Manager open sourced?

this issue is not the same as [Android SDKs don't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822261/android-sdks-dont-show-up)

Answer (score 1):

go back and check what packages are flagged in the avd manager, you can download just 1 image at the time, probably you have selected multiple things or all this are suggested updates.

Comment: i flaged only one, but i have to download seven:(

Answer (score 1):

actually you **no need** to select any SDK for installing the `ARM EABI v7a`

the remaining all are select automatically as an updated version which is available.

So just check only ARM EABI option in your SDK manager to install.

Actually ARM EABI is supporting from only API level 14.

Comment: i checked only eabi, but why sdk manager try to download sdk 2.x and 3.x? does eabi has dependency over them?

Comment: its an recommended when you opened it you need to DeselectAll at the Bottom of your Android SDK Manager window and then you can choose multiple options to install.